# How to insert file metadata into a database (i.e in case of .mp3 files, insert their name, album, artist etc.)

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have a folder with mp3 files that have a title, name , artists and album. Is there a way to insert these details, in a table which has the same columns using PostgreSQL ? Or maybe somehow convert the data into a csv/txt file and then import them? I don't need the files as BLOBS, just the metadata .

Comment: Seems an ideal use-case for a scripting language. Are you familiar with any?

Comment: Yes, i have used a bit of Python in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Install [psycopg2](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg2/)
2. Ensure your PostgreSQL database is functional and ready for use
3. determine how you're going to parse the MP3 file names
4. substitute your parsing logic into the script below

```
import os 
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect('postgres://your_username:your_password@localhost:5432/your_database_name')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('''create table mp3 (
                   id serial,
                   song_title text, 
                   song_name text, 
                   artist text, 
                   album text);''')
con.commit()

for a_file in os.listdir():
    file_name, file_ext = os.path.splitext(a_file)
    if file_ext == '.mp3'
        # substitute line below with your parsing logic
        title, name, artist, album = file_name.split()
        cur.execute('''insert into mp3 (song_title,song_name,artist,album) 
                       values (%s,%s,%s,%s);''',(title,name,artist,album,))
        con.commit()

cur.close()
con.close()
```